# Is It Possible to Remove AjaxDelta from an SP 2013 Master Page?

Tags: 2013, mds, ajaxdelta

Seeing as how the Minimal Download Strategy of SP 2013 is not compatible with the publishing architecture, in a custom master page for a publishing site is it possible to remove the AjaxDelta wrappers around the DelegateControls and such?

Would there be any areas of the site that would be affected by removing the AjaxDelta wrappers to sort of "slim down" the master page?

I'm sure I could just try this, but if someone knows off hand of an issue this would cause I'd rather save myself some tinkering time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the AjaxDelta wrappers does not affect anything else on the site as far as I can tell. I did remove all the AjaxDelta controls to slim down the markup of the rendered pages and everything seems fine. This is a legitimate disadvantage of using the publishing architecture in SharePoint 2013 from a performance perspective.

Comment: is there an attribute on this element that simply disables it? or hides it from the browser?